# Java 6 -> 8 migration: "j.s.c.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available" build error

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a existing maven project which is working fine with the other team members and they were using java 6. I was asked to  upgrade the java version from 6 to 8 and check the compatibility. 
However when I used java 8 I got the error as : 

**"java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate Chaining Error ...."**

So I googled and added .jks file to provide the security key/password for that. 
it resolved the first error/exception but produced another one : **"java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available "**

But then again when i tried to go back to java version 6 I am getting different error/exception as :  
**"Remote host closed connection during handshake : SSL peer shut down incorrectly"**

Please I need some light on this how to resolve it. I have been trying this from past 1 week without any luck. 
I am using maven3 for the building.

Comment: What is the target domain ?

Comment: I'd suggest you enable SSL debug logging -Djavax.net.debug=ssl and post stacktrace related to your error as there could be multiple reasons for that exception. One of them being unexpected keystore format

Comment: @BorysZibrov  , I have enabled   <b>accept untrusted ssl certificate </b> ,so I hope this point is already taken care ....  but I am unable to identify the exact reason for this exception. 
I am also able to connect to the server for which it gives certificate error .... only while maven download i.e maven build  ,  it is throwing this error . 

I have tried creating a blank maven project and compile it , but the result is same

Comment: @Antoniossss I am not sure what do you mean by the target domain.... what you are asking is the server location from where i am trying to get the libs .... so It is one of the NAS location provided by the company from where all libs/jars are downloaded.

Comment: @Abhishek do he ssl debug like Borys suggested

Comment: you said on maven build you got that error , maybe you are trying to build your Java 1.8 project and your maven is looking for another JDK version ? Or  maybe the same while you re trying to run it with a different JDK.....?

Comment: @AntJavaDev As I explained that the application was running on java6 and I had to upgrade it to java 8 . 
So I made some modification in pom file: one of which was the configuration change for artifact id :<b> maven compiler-plugin </b>
previously it was: 
<configuration> 
       <source>1.6</source>
       <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
I modified it to:
<configuration> 
       <source>1.6</source>
       <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: ok thats cool , you changed your project descriptor , doesnt mean smth. Could you please check when you are running `mvn install/build/whatever` , which JAVA version it picks up ? do you have multiple JDK's installed ? one simple way to do it , open up a console(both for windows and linux OS) and type `java -version` and `mvn -version`. Check if the MAVEN->Java_Version matches the default installation, or at least post those info to your question to check that maven is configured properly

Comment: @AntJavaDev Thanks for the response . 
I had installed maven as eclipse plugin and not put in the system path variable( I didn't had the access also). After I added that with the help of responsible team then it started to recognize the setting file and the repository. 
Along with this in my case , I had to add addition .jfk  file to remove the error 


But still I have one doubt : With The same setting in RAD 9.5 the application is not working and still getting the chaining error , but with the downgraded version 8.5 its working fine. 
Is there any major changes in these two versions

Comment: .....RAD you mean IBM toolkit ? you havent mentioned that you are using a web sphere or the IBM tools ...... anyway , i am not quite sure whats the issue with that , the only sure thing is that RAD 9.5 was made to support JDK 1.8. But this is another question

Comment: @AntJavaDev .... I am using RAD 8.5 and WebSphere 8.0....For the update...I have now successfully transferred the application form jdk-6 to jdk-8 using RAD 8.5 
As you have mentioned that RAD 9.5 is made to support JDK 1.8 ...there is a problem I am facing with this RAD version(RAD 9.0 and RAD 9.5). Using this I am still getting handshake error as before ...